# Interbase Error : request depth exceeded. (Recursive definition?)

Tags: interbase, interbase-2009

I currently use Interbase as the DB server for my application, and I've stuck with Interbase 2009 due to its stability in meeting our requirements. We occasionally encounter errors, but this is the first time I've come across the following message: "Request depth exceeded. (Recursive definition?)"

Do you have any ideas or suggestions? I've tried searching online, but haven't had any luck so far.

[image]